# How to get the style of segmented control same as the one in notification center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I am wondering how I can get the style of the segmented control same as notification center, by style I mean the transparent tint color that changes based on the background?
(Also I recognised the height of that is a bit longer comparing to the normal segmented control, is that something custom made? how can I achieve that?)

Please look at this image to view a preview of notificaton center's segmented control

[image]

Comment: The translucent color effect is called `UIVibrancyEffect`, newly available in iOS 8. I haven't tried using it for `UISegmentedControl` yet though.